# Save the state of top level page in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I tried to create a selection page on the top of my root page in my App using `tk.Toplevel()` function in tkinter. The new page has add button which create new option on the selection page. The simplified version of my code is demonstrated below:

```
import tkinter as tk


class demo:
    lines = []
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="+",
                                     command=self.add,
                                     width=3)

        self.add_button.pack()
        self.lines = []


    def add(self):
        line = []
        line.append(tk.Checkbutton(self.master, variable=tk.StringVar(value="0"))) # 5
        self.lines.append(line)
        self.show()
    def show(self):
        self.add_button.pack()
        for l in self.lines:
            l[0].pack()

def new_window(master):        
    NewWindow = tk.Toplevel(master)
    demo(NewWindow)            


root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="selection page",
                             command=lambda: new_window(root),
                             width=30).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What I want is that when I close the new page it maintains its state, i.e. when I create some checkboxs and fill some of them when I close the window it remains the same; but it starts over.

How can I implement that?

Comment: Read about [Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method)

Comment: If you just want to maintain the window through out the instance of the app then `withdrow` is what you want. If you want to maintain the information on following instances you may need to write some JSON file to store a dictionary of all your widgets and their status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for keeping track during just the instance you have open you want to use `withdraw` and `deiconify`. You will also want to control the windows close protocol so it instead withdraws the window.

Take a look at this example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Demo(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_status = False
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.toggle_top)
        self.lines = []
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self, text="+", command=self.add, width=3)
        self.add_button.pack()

    def add(self):
        self.lines.append(tk.Checkbutton(self, variable=tk.StringVar(value="0")))
        self.lines[-1].pack()

    def toggle_top(self):
        if self.hidden_status:
            self.deiconify()
            self.hidden_status = False
        else:
            self.withdraw()
            self.hidden_status = True


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.top = Demo()
        self.top.toggle_top()
        tk.Button(self, text="selection page", command=self.top.toggle_top, width=30).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, this is art! Thanks for answering and tweaking my code

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want with minimal changes, you can hide the `Toplevel` instead of closing it:

```
import tkinter as tk

class demo:
    ...

def new_window(master):
    global NewWindow
    if not NewWindow:
        NewWindow = tk.Toplevel(master)
        NewWindow.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",NewWindow.iconify)
        demo(NewWindow)
    else:
        NewWindow.deiconify()

root = tk.Tk()
NewWindow = None
...

root.mainloop()
```